# Unable "Git stash pop" due to corrupt

Tags: git

I had a lot of changes and some untracked files in local git repository. so i need to

- stashed my changes using (git stash) command
- Then I unstashed them using git stash pop command

But it gives me error:

> git stash pop
>
> error: object file
>   .git/objects/a3/287a7540283ce1993cd5ce455588978f29a12a is empty
>
> fatal: loose object a3287a7540283ce1993cd5ce455588978f29a12a (stored
>   in .git/objects/a3/287a7540283ce1993cd5ce455588978f29a12a) is corrupt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried to remove all my stashes using

```
git stash clear
```

and it's worked for me.. 
Git stash pop corrupt issues resolved